# Insert into table errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code:

```
create table student
( 
    s_id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    s_fname varchar(30) not null,
    s_lname varchar(50) not null,
    s_branch varchar(4) not null,
    pointer float(50) ,
    s_dob date not null
);

drop table student;

select * 
from student;

insert into student (s_fname, s_lname, s_branch, pointer, s_dob)
values (('abc', 'xyz', 'CMPN', 8.5, '1996-03-14'),
        ('lmn', 'pqr', 'EXTC', 7, '1997-03-23')
       );
```

I am unable to rectify what is the error.

Error message I get is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: You dropped the table before you inserted into it...

Comment: lose the parens: `values ('abc','xyz','CMPN',8.5,'1996-03-14'), ('lmn','pqr','EXTC',7,'1997-03-23')`

Comment: You need to remove the drop command, for sure. This is causing your table to not exist when you try to insert into it. Also, your values clause has an extra set of parenthesis around the multiple set of values.

Comment: It looks like you might want to `delete from student;` before selecting from it, let alone inserting into it.

Comment: "The last 3 hours". Seriously? You didn't look at any online examples in that time and spot the difference?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove outermost `()` in `VALUES` clause:

```
create table student
( 
  s_id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
  s_fname varchar(30) not null,
  s_lname varchar(50) not null,
  s_branch varchar(4) not null,
  pointer float(50) ,
  s_dob date not null
);

insert into student (s_fname,s_lname,s_branch,pointer,s_dob)
values
('abc','xyz','CMPN',8.5,'1996-03-14'),
('lmn','pqr','EXTC',7,'1997-03-23');

select * from student;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/RYIRM68664)**</kbd>

And `drop table student;` should be removed/commented too.

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment above, I think your code should be like this:

```
create table student
( 
  s_id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
  s_fname varchar(30) not null,
  s_lname varchar(50) not null,
  s_branch varchar(4) not null,
  pointer float(50) ,
  s_dob date not null
);

--drop table student;


insert into student (s_fname,s_lname,s_branch,pointer,s_dob)
values ('abc','xyz','CMPN',8.5,'1996-03-14'),
('lmn','pqr','EXTC',7,'1997-03-23');

select * from student;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you had a drop table statement to ensure that the table should not exist before you start creation of the table.

the correct way of doing this is like below where we drop the existing `student` table only if it exists, and then create it , populate it and then run a select * on it

```
if object_id('dbo.student', 'u') is not null 
  drop table dbo.student; 

create table student
( 
s_id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
s_fname varchar(30) not null,
s_lname varchar(50) not null,
s_branch varchar(4) not null,
pointer float(50) ,
s_dob date not null
);

insert into student (s_fname,s_lname,s_branch,pointer,s_dob)
values
('abc','xyz','CMPN',8.5,'1996-03-14'),
('lmn','pqr','EXTC',7,'1997-03-23');

select * from student;
```